# How to add facebook sign up in my android app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currentl I am working on an android game. I want to add facebook login to it.Means the users can sign up with their fb account just like Pinterest,QuizUp,etc.Also I need to access the user's friend list.How can I do it ? I tried the official docs on facebook site. But I was unable to do it.Can you please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add facebook to your game you need to add the facebook sdk to and ibrary to  your application and then to add certain information to facebook 
this link can guide you

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/

after this 
To help you get started with the Facebook SDK for Android, we have an interactive guide which leads you through the process set by step including downloading the SDK and configuring a Facebook App ID with your Android app's settings. This guide assumes you're using Eclipse/ADT.
 by this link 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

Use SocialAuth to integrate Facebook API,use below code to get friend's list information.

```
    private final class ResponseListener implements DialogListener 
    {
   public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

      adapter.getContactListAsync(new ContactDataListener());                   
   }
}



// To receive the contacts response after authentication
private final class ContactDataListener implements SocialAuthListener> {

@Override
public void onExecute(List t) {

   Log.d("Custom-UI", "Receiving Data");
   List contactsList = t;
  if (contactsList != null && contactsList.size() > 0) {
  for (Contact c : contactsList) {
    Log.d("Custom-UI", "Contact ID = " + c.getId());
    Log.d("Custom-UI", "First Name = " + c.getFirstName());
    Log.d("Custom-UI", "Last Name = " + c.getLastName());
    }
}
```

Follow the link : [Integrate Facebook API](http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/part-1-using-socialauth-to-integrate-facebook-api-in-android)

Here, you will also get the user's friend list.